# How to setup lint-staged with turbo monorepo?

Tags: monorepo, husky, turbo, lint-staged

I have a turbo monorepo, with `packages/...` and `apps/app-a`, `apps/app-b` .
I have set up husky `pre-commit` hook, which will run `pnpm dlx lint-staged`

I want `lint-staged` to run lint script from the closest to the staged file `package.json` file.
So for example:

1. staged `foo.js` from `apps/app-a` - it will run the `lint` script described in `apps/app-a/package.json`
2. `bar.js` from `apps/app-b` will run `lint` from `apps/app-b/package.json`

etc.

Is that possible?

I tried to setup `lintsatgedrc.json` in the `apps/app-a` and `apps/app-b` folders, with

```json
{
  "*.{ts,tsx}": ["pnpm run lint", "pnpm run check-types"]
}
```

But its always try to run the `lint` and `chack-types` scripts from the monorepo's root `package.json`.